# Factorial for large numbers: product of 32-bit x 128-bit numbers in x86 asm

Tags: assembly, x86, factorial, bigint, largenumber

I want to write a x86 masm program that calculates a big factorials (results up to 128 bits), but I am not sure how to do that. I've written a version that calculates up to 32bits, how could I change it up so that it works for larger numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

128 bits is too big for mul instruction, which saves only 64-bits result (EDX (32bits) + EAX (32bits)).

So first of all you need 4 DWORDS of memory to store 128bits result.
Then you should replace your `mul ebx;` on some procedure call, that can handle 128bits multiplication. The code can be something like this:

```
.data
;...
bignum dword 1, 0, 0, 0; initial answer = 0000 0000 0000 0001h

....
call largemul; replace for mul ebx
....
largemul proc; 
 mov ebx, 10            ;EBX = multiplier
 mov eax, [bignum]  
 mul ebx                ;EDX:EAX = EAX*EBX
 mov [bignum], eax  ;save result
 mov ecx, edx           ;save carried part in ECX

 mov eax, [bignum+4]
 mul ebx
 add eax, ecx           ;add carried part from previous multiplication
 mov [bignum+4], eax
 mov ecx, edx

 mov eax, [bignum+8]
 mul ebx
 add eax, ecx
 mov [bignum+8], eax

 mov eax, [bignum+8]
 mul ebx
 add eax, ecx
 mov [bignum+12], eax
largemul endp;
```

Comment: The last block loads `[bignum+8]` again which was already in EAX.  You probably meant  [bignum+12].  (Also, that top chunk can use `imul ebx, [bignum+12]` since you aren't using its high-half result and you're done with ebx).

Comment: Also, harder to fix, this looks like it's missing carry-propagation from the adds. If `add eax, ecx` carries, there's an extra +1 to apply to the next chunk.  `adc` is handy for this, but unfortunately `mul` destroys FLAGS.  (That's one reason why BMI2 `mulx` exists.  See Intel's white-paper on how to use it for stuff like 512 x 512-bit multiply https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/ia-large-integer-arithmetic-paper.pdf, including comparison against code using just plain `mul` and `adc`).

Comment: **You can `adc edx, 0` after each add** because the high half can't be `0xffffffff`, at most `0xfffffffe`.  So fortunately you can avoid saving carry-out until after the next `mul`.